# I need help about Wordpress Taxonomy List page

Tags: wordpress

Need help, about WordPress custom taxonomy list page I got 404 pagination

I create taxonomy-fundraisers_category.php(taxonomy-{taxonomy-slug}.php)

I use below mention code

```
 $args = array('post_type' => 'fundraiser', 'suppress_filters' => false,'paged' => $paged);
                $args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
                $args['orderby'] = (empty($settings['orderby']))? 'post_date': $settings['orderby'];
                $args['order'] = (empty($settings['order']))? 'desc': $settings['order'];
                $args['paged'] =  ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
                
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

 wp_reset_postdata();
                echo $campaign;
```

Comment: Many Times try permalink but getting 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Taxonomy page, this code should do the job.
By using "wp_query", you get the information of your current query

```
<?php
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      $wp_query->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type());
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

/{fundraiser} => archive

/{fundraiser}/{fundraisers_category} => taxo page

/{fundraiser}/{fundraisers_category}/page/2 => taxo page

Comment: Already I Did this but not working :-( page 1 is working but if I click next page then getting 404

Comment: rebuild permalinks?